# Minimalistically building a test for a simple header using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, gnu-make, googletest

I have a C++ header which contains a class with a method like below. Lets say its a header only library I have.

```
// MyHeader.hpp
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace myheaderonlylibrary {

class MyClass {
public:
    unsigned int Func1(const std::string& str) {
        if (!str.empty())
            return 10;
        else
            return 0;
    }
};

}
```

To test the above method I heve the following gtest source file inside a folder called `unittest` which is like the convention followed.

```
// MyTests.cpp
#include <limits.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "../MyHeader.hpp"

TEST(MyTest, Test_Something) {
    myheaderonlylibrary::MyClass my_object;
    unsigned int expected_value = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(expected_value, my_object.Func1(""));
}
```

All I want to do is build the test using Cmake and run the test. So, following is my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
set(MyheaderOnlyLibrary_HEADERS
    MyHeader.hpp
)

set(MyheaderOnlyLibrary_unittest
    unittest/MyTests.cpp
)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
enable_testing ()
add_executable(MyheaderOnlyLibraryTests ${MyheaderOnlyLibrary_unittest})
```

After the above is set, I do a `cmake ..` and `make` which results with the following error.

```
"_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

**Question:**
I am not a pro in CMake. My question is that if all I want to do is to be able run tests, then should I be doing an `add_executable`? Is this correct approach when the only thing I want is to build and run the tests? Seems like the error when calling `make` is because `add_executable` is looking for `main` method like in a normal executable and its not finding it.

What is the correct way to build a test only project where a header file is the only thing to be tested?

How to run the tests after building? Looks like there is a command `CTest` to run the tests built using CMake?

**Environment:**
I am building this on a macOS with clang as the compiler with C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like a normal C++ program you need to have a main function to execute, for a googletest unit test you can use the following:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
 }
```

This will run your TEST function when executed.

To use ctest to actually run your tests you should have the following lines in your cmake file:

```
find_package(GTest)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include(CTest)
include(GoogleTest)

enable_testing()

target_link_libraries(testName ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

gtest_discover_tests(testName)
```

EDIT:
As an easier place to start before jumping into cmake, I would recommend you start with compiling and running your command on the command line. You can do that with the following:

```
g++ unittest/myunittest.cpp -o unittest/myunittest.out -lgtest -std=c++11
./unittest/myunittest.out
```

Once you know it works, take a look at cmake’s documentation and reproduce your results with a cmake file. Then you can start to scale up your programs. Understanding how to run these commands through the command line will give you an appreciation and a better understanding of what cmake is doing.

Comment: This means that I need to add the `main.cpp` to the `CMakeLists.txt` of course? But then how do you run the test? Same way like any other application?

Comment: Yes, you can run it the same way as a normal application or use the ctest command as you eluded to

Comment: Are you able to build and run this? Seems like it is unable to link to `InitGoogleTest` after adding the main. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Yes you need to link the googletest libraries, cmake can handle this with the lines I added in my edit, you may need to use a higher version of cmake to have access to the `gtest_discover_tests` function

Comment: Seems like we need to define `testName`

Comment: Yes, that was just a placeholder for your actual test name, `MyHeaderOnlyLibraryTest`

Comment: The Cmake version I am using is `3.4` which unfortunately requires some more tweaks to make this work

Comment: Instead of gtest_discover_tests() try gtest_add_tests(). That was the predecessor of discover tests pre-version 3.10. Alternatively, see my edit for building at the command line first

Comment: I got it working. Thanks for your help. All your tips and little bit of tailoring to fix it for my environment and CMake version 3.4 worked!

Comment: Glad I could help!